# Compatibility of C++17 of apple clang++ that xcode 10 beta bundle

Tags: c++, xcode, clang++

clang that bundled with Xcode 10 beta is support c++17?

In Xcode 9, some of C++17 features are not support.
For example, lack of `<filesystem>`, std::optional has bug, and does not support std::variant and so on.

These features already supported opensource clang.

Are they improved at Xcode10 beta?

Comment: Does Clang itself (not Apple's modified version) have complete C++17 support?

Comment: I see compatibility list of clang.
It does not complete c++17 but almost supported.
http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
But apple modified version is lack of some c++17 feature support that opensource clang already supported.

Comment: If you really really want current clang, you can use brew to install LLVM clang.

Comment: how to install it with brew?
I have tried `brew install llvm`
but it does not make symlink on /usr/local

Comment: The `brew info llvm` says `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` to get clang++ to have precedence over Xcode's clang++.  Instead of that, I set up an `alias` to point to the brew installed clang++.

Comment: The full alias I use:  `alias clang17='LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib" /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -std=c++17'`

Comment: I haven't tried it but with my experience i would say replacing the compiler with your home brew for macos and ios (and crosscompilation) will be a time consuming mess.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: It's confirmed by Apple. XCode 10 will not be a C++17 compatible. Whatever this means, it shows that they don't invest enough of their multi billion dollar income in R&D.